# How to authorize certain pages to different users in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

We got assigned to make event-management (Creating College Events with Firebase) application in flutter. Work we did: Creating Event (form) and returning an event card (containing event details in brief) in Homescreen. But we were told to make different pages for certain users like admin and student coordinators who can **only** create an event. While users can **view event only.** With the help of what can we do this?

Is there any library in flutter which we are unaware of?

Do we have to make another layout for admins and another for coordinator and other for users and then connect them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can give different levels of authorization to different people.**

1. Maintain a `users` collection in your Firebase database
2. For each user, create a document. You might already be storing details like `name`, `uid`, `email`, etc. In addition to that, maintain a string field `level`.
3. Upon login, check user's `level`. For instance, if the `level==student` you can display on your homepage only the button that will lead to `event_list_page.dart`.
   If `level==admin`, also display a button to`create_event_page.dart`.

**How will you assign the `level`?**

- If there are only a handful (5-6) admins, manually edit their tag in Firebase console.
- (Assuming email auth) Otherwise, you will have to create a list of email ids of admins, in advance. Then you can simply run a script using Firebase Admin SDK to fetch the user documents of admins from your `users` collection in database.
- If you don't want to use Firebase Admin SDK, you can also write some code in Flutter itself to fetch admin documents and update their tag.